# Getting time from dateTimePicker in date time format?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, outlook

I am working in visual studio and am working on outlook integration for adding new appointments.

Pretty much inside of the software the user must select a date and time using the dateTime component (Using custom format to display time).

I then parse this information into outlook code below:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application outlookApp = 
  new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application(); 
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.AppointmentItem Appointment = 
   (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.AppointmentItem)
    outlookApp.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olAppointmentItem); 

Appointment.Subject = "Appraisal With " + tbFirstName.Text + " " + tbSurname.Text; 
Appointment.Body = "Appraisal with " + tbFirstName.Text + " " + tbSurname.Text + 
  "\n\n Details:\n-----------------------------------------\n First Name: " + 
  tbFirstName.Text + "\nSurname: " + tbSurname.Text + "\n Address: " + tbAddress.Text + 
  "\nDate & Time: " + dtpAppointment.ToString() + "\nContact Number: " + 
  tbPhoneNumber.Text + "\nEmail: " + tbEmail.Text;
Appointment.Location = tbAddress.Text; 
Appointment.ReminderSet = true; 
Appointment.ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = 120; 
Appointment.Importance = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlImportance.olImportanceHigh; 
Appointment.BusyStatus = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlBusyStatus.olBusy;
Appointment.Save();
```

This adds the appointment fine as it is but I need to add the date and the time fields to the appointment and for the life of me I cannot figure it out.

If I use this line:

```
Appointment.Start = dtpAppointment.Value;
```

We get the date okay but the time is always the current time on the computer upon submission. I need the date to go into outlook and the time of appointment to go into it as well.

Comment: What is type of `dtpAppointment` and what is value of `dtpAppointment.Value`?

Comment: Hi Alexi I figured it out. Problem a string into something expected DateTime object, so I needed to convert only the time into string then reconvert only time to DateTime type and push that through.

Comment: Please close your question than.

Answer (score 0):

What is the custom format for you `DateTimePicker`? If the time is not displayed, the `Value` will always be the date selected and the current system time.

Comment: Hi Colin I figured it out. Problem a string into something expected DateTime object, so I needed to convert only the time into string then reconvert only time to DateTime type and push that through.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this one out.

I was pushing a String into a field that expected the DateTime type object.
By default this consisted of the Date and Time so outlook did not know where to put it, in the date or the time section?

I converted only the time to a string.

```
string time = dtpAppointment.Value.ToString("HH:mm");
```

Now that the date and time where separated I passed only the time back into a separate DateTime object.

```
DateTime timeConverted = Convert.ToDateTime(time);
```

I then specified Appointment.Start() argument twice one for the date and the other for the time and it put them into the sections they belong automatically.

Hope this helps others :)

Comment: You don't actually need to convert to a string. Just use the `Hour` and `Minute` properties of DateTime. `Appointment.Start = new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, date.Day, dtpAppointment.Value.Hour, dtpAppointment.Value.Minute, 0);`